# JWT Token Expiry inconsistent

Tags: php, api, laravel-5.1, jwt

I'm still new to laravel, api, as well as JWT. Is there anyone using tymon jwt?

I have been troubling with the Token Expiry. When ever it gets expired, it shows 2 different kinds of errors. Usually, it is just plainly {message: "token_expired"} with a status code of 401, which is fine. But, sometimes it shows up this kind of error, wherein it says it comes from a PayloadValidator, and which I could not trap where I can trigger this. It is a problem for me because its status code is 500 and our frontend developers do not want status code 500.

I would like to make it 400, or rather just have a consistent error response Is there anyone here could help me understand why there 2 kinds of error? How were these encountered?

Occurrence #1: Returns "Status 401 Unauthorized"

```
{
    "error": "token_expired"
}
```

Occurrence #2: Returns "Status 500 Internal Server Error"

```
{
    "message": "Token has expired",
    "status_code": 500,
    "debug": {
    "line": 74,
    "file": "C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel-project\vendor\tymon\jwt-auth\src\Validators\PayloadValidator.php",
    "class": "Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\TokenExpiredException",
    "trace": [
    "#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel-project\vendor\tymon\jwt-auth\src\Validators\PayloadValidator.php(32): Tymon\JWTAuth\Validators\PayloadValidator->validateTimestamps(Array)",
    ....
}
```

[image: Inconsistent TokenExpiry Response]

Comment: Can you go to vendor\tymon\jwt-auth\src\Exceptions and check what statusCode you have in TokenExpiredException.php ? - Also check in PayloadValidator.php if you have any 500 errors .